# What is the most appropriate Angular component/directive/pipe to use to build dynamic HTML like this?

Tags: javascript, angular

(I am coming to Angular from React, so please excuse my question if it seems React centric.)

I need to create an Angular component that takes in a string and a list of terms within that string to show tooltips for.

```
const sentence = "The fox jumped over the moon.";

const tooltips = {
  "text": "jumped over",
  "tooltip": "Blah blah blah."
}, {
  "text": "moon",
  "tooltip" "Object seen in the sky at night."
};
```

The output is expected to look something like this:

```
<div>The fox <span onclick="showTooltip(0)">jumped over</span> the <span onclick="showTooltip(1)">moon</span>.</div>
<div id="tooltip_0">Blah blah blah</div>    
<div id="tooltip_1">Object seen in the sky at night.</div>
```

What is the most appropriate Angular component/directive/pipe to use to create this dynamic structure?

Comment: you can use a component for the single tooltip/word element, and then a custom component that takes in input both the sentence and the tooltips and breaks it down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, you can use `@Input()` to get values from a parent component.

In your `child.ts`, you will have:

`@Input() textInput: string;`

In your `parent.html` you will have:

`<app-child-component [textInput]="variableText"></app-child-component>`

Then you will be able to use the `textInput` in the `child.ts` as any other variable.

More detailed info there: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot simply use `{{textInput}}` in the template (e.g. `child.component.html`). The two inputs need to be combined to produce a dynamic output.

Comment: You can write a function in the `child.component.ts` that will return the value and then call it like so `{{yourFunction(arg1, arg2)}}` in your `child.component.html`. The `@Input()` will let you pass the variable, and then you can use it like if it was native to the component. Additionally look at services to have this kind of content generated especially if it is to be used cross app in mulitple components